# Switch statements logic operator

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn C and I have a question about switch statements.
I want to know if I can write code like this in switch statements.
Can I check the result of a logic comparator like this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    short int day;
    short int month;
    short int year;
    
    printf("Type data day(dd_mm_yyyy)\n");
    
    scanf("%hd%hd%hd",&day,&month,&year);
    
    switch(day > 31 || month > 12)
    {
        case 0 : printf("Valid"); 
                 break;
        default: printf("Invalid");
    }
    
}
```

The idea is to check if `(day > 31 || year > 12)` is true or false in case of false the logic value should be 0 so case 0:, means false, in case of true case 1: which is default.

I hope you guys understand my doubts! Thanks

[Edited]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Include the code directly into the question as formatted text.

Comment: Please don't attach image of the source code/error messages. Please add code as text in the question description.

Comment: `switch` takes an expression that evaluates to an integer value. Whatever you want to use is valid as long as result type is an integer. Besides that I would call that example really bad practice. If you actually only have a `treue`/`false` option, use an `if` instead of a `switch`.

Comment: BTW: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Not knowing that you should not post images of code is one thing. But you're expected to correct it when we point it out.

Comment: I'm not going to look at the picture of your code, but the expression `(day > 31 || year > 12)`  looks pointless anyway, it should probably be (`day > 31 || month > 12`). Why should a year larger than 12 be a problem?

Comment: Why at all do you use a `switch` where an `if` suffices?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know is to test it yourself:

```c
short int day = 4;
short int month = 5;
short int year = 6;

switch (day > 31 || year > 12)
{
case 0:
    printf("Valid");
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid");
    break;
}
```

This produces the output: `Valid`

The reason to that is you're passing a *logic expression*, which gets evaluated to `0` (true) or `1` (false), which is an integer expression.

In fact, from the **Current C Programming Language Standard** – [ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) you can read:

> **6.8.4.2 The switch statement**
> **Constraints**
> **1** The controlling expression of a **switch** statement shall have integer type.
> **2** If a **switch** statement has an associated **case** or **default** label within the scope of an
> identifier with a variably modified type, the entire **switch** statement shall be within the
> scope of that identifier.154)
> **3** The expression of each **case** label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
> the **case** constant expressions in the same **switch** statement shall have the same value
> after conversion. There may be at most one **default** label in a **switch** statement.
> (Any enclosed **switch** statement may have a **default** label or **case** constant
> expressions with values that duplicate **case** constant expressions in the enclosing
> **switch** statement.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you can write code like this? The answer is definitely **yes**.

Should you write code like this? The answer is definitely **no**.

The value of the expression `(day > 31 || year > 12)` is by definition 1 if the condition is true and 0 if the condition is wrong.

What you should do in order to experiment this is just print the value like this:

```
printf("%d\n", day > 31 || year > 12);
```

and in a real program:

```
if (day > 31 || year > 12)
   // take action if date is wrong
else
   // take action if date is correct
```

BTW: the `day > 31 || year > 12` condition is fishy. Read my comment above.